# Laravel groupBy column and add totals based on Quantity column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a pivot table in Laravel (order_product) which records each product which belongs to an order.

I use the following columns "**order_id, product_id, qty**"

If I use

```
DB::table('order_product')->selectRaw('*, count(*)')->groupBy('product_id');
```

I get the count of each product occurrence.

Some products, however, occur more than once in an order. How do I multiply each product by the **qty** column and then group by **product_id** and count them together?

At the end I need to get the total count of all orders grouped by product.

**EDIT**
Here's my database table

[image]

Desired output:

Product (ID = 30) occurs **5** times in the table, from 5 different orders. The product total multiplied by the quantity columns would equal to **13**

Comment: Please post table structure, sample data and desired output

Comment: @lad2025 edited the post. have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to aggregate using the sum of the quantity field, for each product.  Hence, the following should work:

```
DB::table('order_product')->selectRaw('product_id, SUM(qty)')->groupBy('product_id');
```

This would correspond to the following raw MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    product_id,
    SUM(qty)
FROM order_product
GROUP BY
    product_id
```